# Firebase wants to charge me, but i'm using the test account

Tags: firebase, console, google-cloud-platform

I made the cloud platform test account, which makes $ 300 available for a year.
Now I want to integrate the firebase into my project, but when I create a project on the console, it says it will be charged. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review this page on Google's website for more information about what is included in `free` for firebase. The Spark Plan is free, but you are limited to one per project. Select the correct plan based upon your needs from `Spark Plan`, `Flame Plan` or `Blaze Plan`.

[Firebase Pricing Plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)